# Space between answer choices in mcexam

Tags: mcexam

Is there a way to increase globally the separation between answer choices in /mcanswerslist of mcexam?  I can do it by manually typing a newline command after each choice.  It would be very convenient if I were able to control this globally, or at least for each question.

```
%%% Copyright (c) 2017 Jorre Vannieuwenhuyze.
%%%
%%% Permission is granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this
%%% software under the terms of the LaTeX Project Public License
%%% (LPPL), version 1.3c or any later version.
%%%
%%% This software is provided 'as is', without warranty of any kind,
%%% either expressed or implied, including, but not limited to, the
%%% implied warranties of merchantability and fitness for a
%%% particular purpose.

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[output=exam
       ,numberofversions=2
       ,version=2
       ,seed=1
       ,randomizequestions=false
       ,randomizeanswers=false
       ,writeRfile=true
       ]{mcexam}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{mcquestions}
\question Question
    \begin{mcanswerslist}
    \answer Answer1 no extra space
    \answer [correct] Answer2
\end{mcanswerslist}
\question Question
    \begin{mcanswerslist}
    \answer Answer1 extra space between answer choices \\
    \answer [correct] Answer2\\
    \end{mcanswerslist}
\end{mcquestions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would try increasing \itemsep.  If not, one would need to study mcexam documentation and source code.

Comment: Unfortunately \itemsep has no effect in mcanswerslist.

Comment: Take a look at the sections 5.3 and 5.4 in the `mcexam` manual. In those two suggestions are given how to change the default settings including the spacing and layout of questions and answers.